# Notes user set up IDVault error: IDVGetVOCertChain: Note item not found

Tags: lotus-domino

Update: I posted this in the wrong forum in error, moved to ServerFault.

Domino server 8.5.3 Windows 2008 R2
Notes Client 8.5.1

As part of policy documents, new registered users have their ID uploaded to an ID Vault. I have enabled some ID vault debug settings.
The problem I have is: on installing Notes client on PC for first time, user receives "Wrong Password" prompt. I believe the user record is being found correctly in the vault:
01/08/2013 07:21:29 IDVAULT: idsync.c nwall; FileChunkSize 16384; WantDnLoad 1; WantUpLoad 0; WantCerts 0; WantChallengeC 0; UpFileHasPW: 0; TE0 0; TE1 0; TE2 1; TE3 1

But I see this, which looks like a certificate failure of some sort.
01/08/2013 07:21:29 IDVAULT: idsync.c FetchArtifacts: IDVGetVOCertChain: Note item not found
01/08/2013 07:21:29 IDVAULT: idsync.c IDVSrvDlgSync: FetchArtifacts: Note item not found

If I then extract the ID from the vault, copy to the PC, set up continues as normal, so there would not appear to be anything wrong with the ID...?

The only references I can find online for above server messages, I have found here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27037703&aid=1
http://lotusnotus.com/lotusnotus_en.nsf/dx/a-little-story-about-an-error-with-id-vault....htm
...but I am fairly certain they do not apply to my situation.

Anyone with any pointers or comments would be greatly received.

Here's a larger chunk of server output when running Notes Client setup for user: nwall

```
01/08/2013 07:21:05 IDVAULT: idvdb.c IDVFindIDInVault: Exiting: No error
01/08/2013 07:21:05 IDVAULT: download.c IDVServerDialogDnLoad: IDVLookupUserIDInfo: No error
NAMELookup::<NIFGetInternetDomain> getting internet domain information.
01/08/2013 07:21:29 IDVAULT: download.c IDVServerDialogDnLoad: IDVServerStartSyncDialog: No error
01/08/2013 07:21:29 IDVAULT: idsync.c nwall; FileChunkSize 16384; WantDnLoad 1; WantUpLoad 0; WantCerts 0; WantChallengeC 0; UpFileHasPW: 0; TE0 0; TE1 0; TE2 1; TE3 1
NAMELookup::<NIFGetInternetDomain> getting internet domain information.
NAMELookup::<Lookup> PID:TID ( F54: 7) start of routine
NAMELookup::<lookup> Searching view '$Users' (1 of 1 views).
NAMELookup::<lookup> Searching name='nwall'
```

(1 of 1 names).
NAMELookup:: Searching DBIndex=1.
NAMELookup:: from cache took 0 msecs
NAMELookup:: NumReturned=1, TotalNumReturned=1 match(es) for name='nwall'
NAMELookup:: Skipping to next view/namespace (stop at first match)!
NAMELookup:: locate namespace in DBIndex=1, view='$ServerAccess'
NAMELookup:: locate namespace in DBIndex=1, view='$PoliciesByGroup'
01/08/2013 07:21:29 IDVAULT: idsync.c FetchArtifacts: IDVGetVOCertChain: Note item not found
01/08/2013 07:21:29 IDVAULT: idsync.c IDVSrvDlgSync: FetchArtifacts: Note item not found

Comment: This is not a programming question, so it belongs on ServerFault instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: @Richard,  My mistake, I posted here on "autopilot" moved to ServerFault.